# Catching form submissions in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a URL route that has a parameter whose value is not known ahead of time when the page is loaded. For example:

/read/book/page/:page

But when the user is selection screen they get to type in which page number they want to start on then click submit. Is it possible to catch this form submission and place it in the URL? Normally there is a question mark (?) right because its a GET request. But Backbone how can backbone catch that?

Comment: Can you have the server rewrite the url based on the querystring? If not, then just parse the querystring yourself in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

## Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/PT2tU/

## JS:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : function () {
        return 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json?page=' + this.get('page');
    },
    // remove it
    parse : function (response) {
        response || (response = {});
        response.justToTriggerChangeEvent = Math.random();
        return response;
    },
    getPageContent : function () {
        return 'Here should be page a content for page #' + this.get('page');
    }
});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '[data-page]',
    events : {
        'submit' : 'submit'
    },
    initialize : function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.showPage);
    },
    showPage : function () {
        this.$('[data-page-content]').html(this.model.getPageContent());
    },
    submit : function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = this.$('[data-page-num]').val();
        if (page) {
            app.navigate('read/book/page/' + page, true);
        }
    }
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        'read/book/page/:page' : 'page'
    },
    initialize : function (options) {
        this.bookModel = options.bookModel;
    },
    page : function (page) {
        this.bookModel.set('page', page);
        this.bookModel.fetch();
    }
});

var model = new Model();
var view = new View({model:model});
var app = new Router({bookModel:model});

Backbone.history.start();
```

## HTML:

```
<div data-page>
    <form>
        <label><input type="text" data-page-num /></label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div data-page-content></div>
</div>
```